Laravel Scout: any way to get all words with a given Levenshtein index?
I have implemented a Laravel Scout / tntSearch based fuzzy search for words in a MySql database. The search is working so far, but it's not really what I'm aiming for. Rather than getting ideally a single word that is similar to a given, potentially misspelled string, I'd like to get all words that are similar to a given, correct word. If I pass in that word, I'm getting back that word itself, which is kind of expected, but not what I want.
Example as is:
in: Sache - out: Sache
Example as intended:
in: Sache - out: Bache, Wache, Drache...
So, is there any configuration option (or maybe another search driver) that can help me achieve this goal?
